# How to specify bean to be initialize base on conditional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I'm having a factory that have to be create base on config.property value

```
  @Service
  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  @ConditionalOnProperty("'${config.property}==a' or '${config.property}==b'")
  public class CustomFactory {
    private final SpecificActionOnA specificActionOnA;
    private final SpecificActionOnB specificActionOnB;
 }
```

To succeed to create a bean of type `CustomFactory` I'm oblige to pass all conditions to each SpecificAction Component the signature of `SpecificActionOnA` and `SpecificActionOnB` are respectively

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty("'${config.property}==a'or '${config.property}==b'")
public class SpecificActionOnA {}

@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty("'${config.property}==a' or '${config.property}==b'")
public class SpecificActionOnB {}
```

My expectation is to have this definition for my SpecificAction that will not load SpecificActionOnA on condition b and SpecificActionOnB on condition a respectively.

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty("'${config.property}==a'")
public class SpecificActionOnA {}

@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty("'${config.property}==b'")
public class SpecificActionOnB {}
```

Since the difference with the factory is too small for me to create a specific factory for each case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you only need one of the two SpecificAction in your CustomFactory, you can

- create an interface `SpecificAction`
- create two separate implementations for the interace `SpecificActionOnA` and `SpecificActionOnB`,
- add appropriate conditions to the two implementations
- use/autowire the interface in your customFactory

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved my issue by rearranging my code like this :

- CustomFactory

  ```
  @ConditionalOnProperty("'${config.property}===a' or '${config.property}===b'")
  public class CustomFactory {
    private final SpecificActionResolver specificActionResolver;

    @Value("${config.property}")
    private String property;

    SpecificAction specificAction = specificActionResolver.get(property);
  }
  ```
- I create a resolver class SpecificActionResolver

  ```
  public class SpecificActionResolver {
    public SpecificAction get(String property) {
       //Add logic to create specific bean here
       if ("a".equals(property)) return new SpecificActionOnA();
       else if ("b".equals(property)) return new SpecificActionOnB();
       return null;
    }
  }
  ```
- I make my component `SpecificActionOnA` and `SpecificActionOnB` implement an interface `SpecificAction`

  ```
  @Component
  @ConditionalOnProperty("'${config.property}===a'")
  public class SpecificActionOnA implements SpecificAction {}

  @Component
  @ConditionalOnProperty("'${config.property}===b'")
  public class SpecificActionOnB implements SpecificAction {}
  ```